# Emacs SLIME Common Lisp Undefined variable

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I'm following [Practical Common Lisp](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/) [Chapter 3](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html) codes.

I've save the following codes to an external files:

```
(defvar *db* nil)

(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(defun add-record (cd) (push cd *db*))

(defun dump-db ()
  (dolist (cd *db*)
    (format t "\~{\~a:\~10t\~a\~%\~}\~%" cd)))
```

I keep getting the following error when I tried to compile it inside Emacs:

```
compilation unit finished ;
Undefined variable: ;
*DB* ;
caught 1 WARNING condition
```

Could someone explain to me what is wrong with the code?

What is the different between compiling the above code vs running each line under SLIME?

thanks in advance.

the following is what i tried:

1. If i try compile all the above codes (cursor at very end), i get the undefined variable warning.
2. if i try and compile
   `(defvar *db* nil)`
   then rest of the code, I don't get the undefined variable warning (i tried this just before posting, but i was not getting this result in previous attempt, or maybe i did something extra in those previous attempts...).
   i think i understand why I'm not getting an error with the 2nd method because the `*db*` is in memory already.

Comment: how you compile it in emacs? Which key strokes or `M-x` commands yo use?

Comment: you may not execute just the last/next expression, but a region or a whole buffer. There are typically commands to do that. See `c-h m` for commands in GNU Emacs, which are available for that buffer.

Comment: You are certainly compiling just the last form.  You need to compile the whole buffer.

Comment: Please try this. Save the file. Use `C-c C-k' to compile the whole file, Does this work?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim:  I used C-c C-c as per Chapter 3.

Comment: C-c C-c compiles only individual functions.

Answer (score 0):

See the SLIME manual: [Compilation Commands](https://slime.common-lisp.dev/doc/html/Compilation.html#Compilation)

<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> only compiles individual toplevel forms. See the documentation how to compile a region or file.

Comment: thanks. I must not have read or mix up the compilation output at one stage, because i thought i did have all code compiled with C-c C-c at one stage. I must have mixed up the output from following the book vs compiling from the text file (the text file is where I store all the variables and function from the chapter).

Answer (score 0):

As the people commented - that was also my suspicion that you didn't run the compiling command for the entire buffer.

To compile the entire file/buffer, do: `C-c C-k`.
Or mark all the code you want by
`C-S-` and for up `p`, down `n`, back `b`, forward `f` to be run
and then call `M-x slime-compile-region`.

Comment: thanks. What you noted work. Look like I got mix up following the book and compiling the text file.